# How to display time/clock using dojo or dijit?

Tags: javascript, dojo, clock

Basically, I just need to display the current time (hh:mm:ss am/pm format) inside an html input text box.  And since this will serve as a clock, the time should continue counting/moving on while it is being displayed.

I can do this in plain javascript, but I would like to see a dojo/dijit implementation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [example](http://sam-i-am.com/work/sandbox/simplClock/test_DojoClock.html) that you may reuse.

You could also implement this on your own, using [dojox.timing.Timer](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/timing.html).

```
dojo.require('dojox.timing');
t = new dojox.timing.Timer(1000);
t.onTick = function() {
   //One second elapsed
   var now = new Date();
   //format now using dojo.date.locale.format
   //update your text box with the result
}
t.onStart = function() {
   //Do whatever setup is needed
}
t.start();
```

A couple of examples for [dojo.date.locale.format](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/date/locale/format.html#a-simple-example-formatting-a-date-in-a-number-of-ways).

Comment: Thanks. I actually already saw that but it just seems too much lines of code for such a small functionality (even if I just grab the sections for plain clock code).  I was hoping there's a shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

for the minimalist approach, you could probably just achieve this with an input control and a setTimeout call to dojo.date.locale.format.  You don't necessarily need DojoX/Dijit abstractions here, though some of the dojox.timing code can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code below:

```
var myTime = new dijit.form.TimeTextBox({
    value: new Date()
    constraints: {
        timePattern: 'hh:mm:ss a',
    },
    id: "timeTb"
}, dojo.byId("timeDiv"));

var elem = document.getElementById("timeTb");
setInterval(function(){
    dijit.byId("timeTb").setValue(new Date());
}, 1000);
```